# Logstash error when converting MySQL value to nested elasticsearch property on suggestion field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

A Huge cry for help here, When i try to convert a MySQL value to a nested elasticsearch field using logstash i get the following error.

```
{"exception"=>"expecting List or Map, found class org.logstash.bivalues.StringBiValue", "backtrace"=>["org.logstash.Accessors.newCollectionException(Accessors.java:195)"
```

Using the following config file:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data"
        jdbc_user => "username"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        statement => "SELECT id, suggestions, address_count FROM `suggestions` WHERE id <= 100"
        jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
        jdbc_page_size => "50000"
    }
}
filter {
  mutate {
  rename => { 'address_count' => '[suggestions][payload][count]' }
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => [
        "localhost:9200"
    ]
        index => "dev_suggestions"
        document_type => "address"
    }
}
```

**However if i rename address_count to a field that is not already in my mapping, Then it works just fine and it correctly adds the value as a nested property**, I have tried on other fields in my index and not just suggestions.payloads.address_count and i get the same issue, **It only works if the field has not been defined in the mapping.**

This has caused me some serious headaches and if anyone could help me out to overcome this issue i would greatly appreciate it as Ive spent the last 48 hours  banging my head on the table!

I initially assumed i could do the following with a MySQL query:

```
SELECT id, suggestion, '[suggestions][payload][count]' FROM `suggestions` WHERE id <= 100
```

Then i also tried

```
SELECT id, suggestion, 'suggestions.payload.count' FROM `suggestions` WHERE id <= 100
```

Both failed to insert the value with the later option giving an error that a field can not contain dots.

And finally the mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "address": {
      "properties": {
        "suggestions": {
          "type": "completion",
          "payloads" : true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Thanks to Val** - and for future users in the same situation as myself that need to convert MySQL data into nested Elasticsearch objects using logstash, **Here is a working solution using Logstash 5 and Elasticsearch 2.***

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data"
        jdbc_user => "username"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        statement => "SELECT addrid, suggestion, address_count FROM `suggestions` WHERE id <= 20"
        jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
        jdbc_page_size => "50000"
    }
}

filter {
  ruby {
       code => "
           event.set('[suggestions][input]', event.get('suggestion'))
           event.set('[suggestions][payload][address_count]', event.get('address_count'))
           event.set('[v][payload][id]', event.get('addrid'))
       "
       remove_field => [ 'suggestion', 'address_count', 'addrid' ]
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [
            "localhost:9200"
        ]
        index => "dev_suggestions"
        document_type => "address"
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of ES do you have?

Comment: Can you also show what kind of record your SQL statement spits out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to proceed differently. First, I would rename the `suggestions` field in your SQL query to something else and then build the `suggestions` object from the values you get from your SQL query.

```
    statement => "SELECT id, suggestion, address_count FROM `suggestions` WHERE id <= 100"
```

Then you could use a `ruby` filter (and remove your `mutate` one) in order to build your `suggestions` field, like this:

Logstash 2.x code:

```
ruby {
     code => "
         event['suggestions']['input'] = event['suggestion']
         event['suggestions']['payload']['count'] = event['address_count']
     "
     remove_field => [ 'suggestion', 'address_count' ]
}
```

Logstash 5.x code:

```
ruby {
     code => "
         event.set('[suggestions][input]', event.get('suggestion'))
         event.set('[suggestions][payload][count]', event.get('address_count'))
     "
     remove_field => [ 'suggestion', 'address_count' ]
}
```

PS: All this assumes you're using ES 2.x since the `payload` field has disappeared in ES 5.x

Comment: Thaks for taking the time out to help Val, i was litterally at the end of the road with no idea what to do next.. hoping you would save the day! I get the following error but will be able to look into it more as soon as i get back home.     [2017-08-09T08:25:39,002][ERROR][logstash.filters.ruby    ] Ruby exception occurred: Direct event field references (i.e. event['field']) have been disabled in favor of using event get and set methods (e.g. event.get('field')). Please consult the Logstash 5.0 breaking changes documentation for more details.

Comment: P.S -- im a using ES 2.3.1,  I will be back home in 45 minutes.

Comment: Are you using Logstash 5 with ES 2.3.1?

Comment: I think it is logstash 5 yes, I just thought the same thing! and thought i bet thats why? Its because i have been testing between ES 5.5 and 2.3.1

Comment: I've updated my answer with Logstash 5 compliant code.

Comment: Val, you are an absolute freaking life saver.. Know that you have done a very good deed for a man in need haha! Without your help i would not have been able to do this and would have wasted another 2 days trying different configurations. I have no ruby experience what so ever so it was all a bit overwhelming for me but i guess we all need to ask for help at some point especially when we are just starting out. You have helped me move past a huge stopping block within my project and for that i am truly appreciative for your time and support, Wish i could TIP you 50$ when its more than deserved.